# Transferring all SVN repositories to another server

Tags: svn, repository

I'm moving to a new machine and i'm hoping to transfer my repositories as easily as possible. I  have had a quick look around and have seen people using SVN dump.

As i'm planning on copying all repositories can I simply copy the c:/repositories folder ?

I'm using visual SVN on windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Chapter 5](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html.) of [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html).

To move a repository from one server to another you will want to use the `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` commands.

> Subversion provides such functionality
>   by way of repository dump streams. A
>   repository dump stream (often referred
>   to as a “dump file” when stored as a
>   file on disk) is a portable, flat file
>   format that describes the various
>   revisions in your repository—what was
>   changed, by whom, when, and so on.
>   This dump stream is the primary
>   mechanism used to marshal versioned
>   history—in whole or in part, with or
>   without modification—between
>   repositories. And Subversion provides
>   the tools necessary for creating and
>   loading these dump streams: the
>   svnadmin dump and svnadmin load
>   subcommands, respectively.

The usage of svn dump is

`svnadmin dump reponame > dumpfile`

and the usage of svn load is

`svnadmin load reponame < dumpfile`.

The help page for VisualSVN that references the usage of `svnadmin dump` can be found [here](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/dump/) and `svnadmin load` [here](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/load/).